# Selecting the tool of choice (Wordplay)

Tags: wordplay

Your brothers have taken over your bedroom for over a week! However, you know you're powerless to move them unless you can solve their quest:

"Bring the tool that best describes this room."

You head to the garage to pick your weapon of choice, but which one do you pick and why?

**HINT**

> The puns are strong with this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a

> broom?

Reasoning:

> broom is a portmanteau of bro and room.

---

Previous answer which I think is wrong:
Or maybe, it's a

> Generator

Because

> You're powerless without it.

---

Previous answer:
Is it a

> level?

Reasoning:

> "you can solve their *quest*", and a quest is like a level in video games

Comment: Awesome line of thinking; I hadn't thought of that solution. Unfortunately, that isn't the answer. However, rot13(gurer ner n srj pbagrkghny uvagf gb nvq gur qrpvfvba bhgfvqr bs gurve dhrfg qrfpevcgvba).

Comment: @user3303504 i added some new guesses

Comment: rot13(Bar bs lbhe nafjref vf pbeerpg, ohg gur ernfbavat vf bss.)

Comment: I added some more explanation to one of them. I think it makes more sense now

Comment: rot13(Pbeerpg nafjre, ohg gur rkcynangvba vf sne fvzcyre, naq jurer gur jbeq-cynl ryrzrag pbzrf va.)

Comment: rot13(Vf vg whfg orpnhfr vg pbagnvaf ebbz?)

Comment: rot13(Nyzbfg. Gurer ner crbcyr vafvqr vg nf jryy.)

Comment: Ah, I see, I changed my reasoning again.

Answer (score 0):

Since my bedroom's decoration is

> lively and cheerful,

the tool that best describes it would be

> the **chipper**.